# Attempting to invoke a function causes an identifier not found error

Tags: c++-cli

I want to call a function in my source from a button-click handler, but I get an identifier not found error.
In my header I have this code:

```
private:
    System::Void onepone_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        AddOnePlusOne();
    }
```

I have in my source (among other stuff):

```
#include "MyForm.h"

void AddOnePlusOne()
{
    int one = 1;
    int two = one + one;
    MessageBox::Show("one plus one equals " + two.ToString());
}
```

This function works fine if I put it into the header. But it feels strange to me to run all code from the header.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I agree with you. In the old C/C++ times, the header file was for type declarations only, while the "real code" was in the .c or .cpp file. However, when programming C++/CLI, you need to get used to the fact that the old times are over. Now everything happens in the .h files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because decoration of function `void AddOnePlusOne()` is not available in header file `MyForm.h`. So when its call is encountered in function `private: System::Void onepone_Click(System::Object^  sender,   System::EventArgs^  e)` then compiler is unable to identify it.
Provide declaration of function `void AddOnePlusOne()` in header `MyForm.h` and it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I added void `AddOnePlusOne();` in the header, and changed the function declaration in the cpp-file to `void MMCuda04::MyForm::AddOnePlusOne()` (or rather VS did). Now it works great!